# How to use "OnClick.AddListener" on multiple GameObjects in one Frame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm pretty new to Unity and C# scripting.

In my scene I have four buttons. I declared them in my script as public and put the items (on type Button) via drag and drop in my inspector in unity. Depending on which button is clicked, i want my program to do something. You can see in the script below what I've done. That scripts works perfectly just like I want it to.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button Left;
    public Button Right;
    public Button Starten;
    public Button Zurueck;

    private void Start()
    { 
        loadRezept(0);
        Right.onClick.AddListener(iterationUp);
        Left.onClick.AddListener(iterationDown);
        Starten.onClick.AddListener(starten);
        Zurueck.onClick.AddListener(zurueck);
    }


... (here are the methods "iterationUp" and so on...)
```

This script work perfectly. But now there is my question: how can I do the same on using gameobjects?

If I just change the type "Button" to "GameObject" I don't have the possibility to use "onClick.AddListener". I don't want a script for every single gameobject. I just want something like I posted above.

Comment: loop over the objects?

Comment: Why do you want GameObject?

Comment: @derHugo: I'm working with the myo armband (https://neurosciencenews.com/shop/neuroscience-clothing/myo-gesture-control-armband-black/) and I need something like a "Highlight"-funktion to show which object would be selected.

Answer (score 0):

`GameObject` itself has no such events.

---

Sounds like what you are asking for is a custom [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html)

You can create your own component like e.g.

```
public class HighlightController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent OnHighlight;

    // Somewhere Invoke the event e.g.
    public void SetHighlighted()
    {
        OnHighlight.Invoke();
    }
}
```

where you can add listeners now either via code or via the Inspector (just like the `onClicked`).

So put this on your `GameObject`s and then e.g. have fields like

```
[SerializeField] private HighlightController highlight;
//etc...

private void Awake()
{
    highlight.OnHighlight.AddListener(HandleHighlight);
    //etc...
}

private void HandleHighlight ()
{
    ...
}

// Make sure to cleanup listeners when not needed anymore
private void OnDestroy()
{
    highlight.OnHighlight.RemoveListener(HandleHighlight);
    //etc...
}
```

---

Or yes as mentioned as simple `event` could do the same without the serialization:

```
public class HighlightController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action OnHighlight;

    public void SetHighlighted ()
    {
        OnHighlight?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

and do

```
private void Awake()
{
    highlight.OnHighlight += HandleHighlight;
}

private void OnDestroy ()
{
    highlight.OnHighlight -= HandleHighlight;
}
```

Comment: If there is no need to serialize the event or interact with it in the inspector, and listeners are all added and removed via code (like in the example) a C# delegate or delegate object would also suffice.

Comment: @NSJacob1 yes .. or you could simply use a `public event Action` in this case .. but since OP wanted something similar to `onClick` a `UnityEvent` would do as well ;)